# Replacing specific value in a column from a list

Tags: r, list, replace

searched a bit throughout the forum, sorry, beginner question ...

I have a list called Data, with two columns, named "dates" and "countries"
I'd like to replace a specific value in the column country, here is what I try

```
Data[Data$countries == "GE",]<-"DE"
```

It computes, but when I display Data, I still find the GE value...

Answer (score 1):

We need to assign it to the column (assuming that the column is `character` class) instead of the whole dataset

```
Data$countries[Data$countries == "GE"] <- "DE"
```